# Simple Compactness and Continuity Proof Verification

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

I'm given the following:
Let $X$ be a compact metric space, $g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $g$ continuous and $g(x)\ne0$  $\forall x\in X$.

And I need to prove that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|g(x)|\ge\delta$ $\forall x\in X$.
I've gone about it using a few results.

Proof: Consider $|g|:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Since $g$ is continuous, $|g|$ is also continuous. Furthermore, since the image of a continuous function with a compact domain is itself compact, $|g|$ maps $X$ to a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. By Heine-Borel, compactness in $\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to closed and boundedness. Then, since $|g(x)|$ is bounded from below, we can pick $\delta>0$ such that $\delta=\inf_{x\in X}|g(x)|$, so we get $|g(x)|\ge\delta$ for all $x\in X$.

Does this proof suffice?

Comment: Your proof is correct. An alternative way: for each $x\in X$ using continuity of $g$ find an open nbd $U_x$ of $x$ such that $\big|g(y)-g(x)\big|<\frac{|g(x)|}{2}$ for each $y\in U_x$, i.e., $|g(x)|-|g(y)|\leq\big|g(y)-g(x)\big|<\frac{|g(x)|}{2}$ for each $y\in U_x$. So, $|g(y)|>\frac{|g(x)|}{2}$ for each $y\in U_x$. Consider the open cover $\{U_x:x\in X\}$ of $x$ and find a finite subcover $\{U_{x_1},...,U_{x_n}\}$ of this cover using compactness of $X$. Let $\delta:=\displaystyle\min_{1\leq i\leq n}\frac{|g(x_{i})|}{2}$. Then, $|g(x)|\geq \delta>0$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: Your reasoning that $\delta>0$ may require some elaboration. $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ are also bounded from below

Comment: Also, taking the absolute value is unnecessary, in my opinion. The complement of the image of $g$ contains 0 and is open. By definition of the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ that means there is an open interval around 0 that does not intersect the image of $g$.

Comment: @Bananach in regards to your first comment, I figured it was clear that $inf_{x\in X}|g(x)|=\delta>0$ since $|g(x)|\ne 0$. But you're right, there is a bit of a leap there. Do you have any recommendations for clarifying this gap? I figured that since the image would be a closed set, the infimum would be the least point in the set, which would be greater than zero.

Comment: Which part of my suggested solution are unclear?

Comment: It is true that the infimum is attained but depending on where you are in your education you'll have to prove that. Even if you don't have to prove it, you have to cite it properly

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

A real valued continuous function on a compact space attains its infimum (because $g(X)$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$, hence closed and bounded), $\exists~p \in X $ such that $|g(p)|=\inf_{x \in X}|g(x)|$. This $|g(p)|>0$ by your assumption, so $\exists~\delta>0$ such that for any $x \in X$,   $|g(x)|\geq |g(p)|>\delta$.

Comment: The fact that a continuous real valued function on a compact domain attains its infimum doesn't follow from boundedness of its image

Comment: In other words, saying "$g$ attains its infimum because $g(X)$ is ... bounded" is plain wrong

Comment: It was correct sans one word. Boundedness ensures the existence of the extremums and closedness ensures they belong to $g(X)$.